I have added assert but while running test it is getting failed with this error ' Assertion Failed: Expected: null, Actual: Meeting Held'
Actual class
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void syncMeetingOutcome(String appId, String outcome){
        ServiceAppointment sa = [SELECT AccountId, Id, appointmentType, SchedStartTime, Service_Resource__c, Service_Resource__r.relatedrecord.FirstName, Service_Resource__r.relatedrecord.LastName, Service_Resource__r.Lob__c, Service_Resource__r.relatedrecord.FederationIdentifier , ServiceTerritoryId, ServiceTerritory.DndNumber__c, Customer_TimeZone__c FROM ServiceAppointment where id =: appId];
        List<Service_Appointment_Attendee__c> attendeeList = [SELECT Id, Employee_SID__c,Lob__c, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c, Service_Appointment__c, DndNumber__c FROM Service_Appointment_Attendee__c where Service_Appointment__c = :appId];
        
        CastPkg_XLOBService castLOB = (CastPkg_XLOBService) CastPkg_XLOBService.getXLOBService();
        if(attendeeList == null || attendeeList.size() == 0){
            return;
        }
     
        String dnd = sa.ServiceTerritory.DndNumber__c;
        if(dnd.startsWith('P'))
            dnd = dnd.substring(1);
        //ServiceTerritoryMember member = castLOB.getServiceTeritoryMember(sa.Service_Resource__r.relatedrecord.FederationIdentifier, dnd, CastUtils.getAppointmentTypeEnum(sa.appointmentType)); 

        List<CastPkg_XLOBUtils.Employee> employeeList= new List<CastPkg_XLOBUtils.Employee>(); 

        employeeList.add( new CastPkg_XLOBUtils.Employee(attendeeList.get(0).Employee_SID__c, attendeeList.get(0).Lob__c, attendeeList.get(0).First_Name__c, attendeeList.get(0).Last_Name__c, 'SENDER', attendeeList.get(0).DndNumber__c ));
        CastPkg_XLOBUtils.AppointmentSfRequest request = new CastPkg_XLOBUtils.AppointmentSfRequest(sa.AccountId, null, sa.SchedStartTime);
        request.appointmentId  = appId; 
        request.Attendees= new CastPkg_XLOBUtils.Attendees();
        request.Attendees.employees= employeeList;
        request.availability.javaTimeZoneName = sa.Customer_TimeZone__c;

        request.appointmentOutcome = outcome;
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            ServiceAppointment result2  = castLOB.updateXlobAppointment( request ) ;
        }
    }
}

test class
@IsTest
static void testDispositionXlob1(){
    Account ac = [Select Id, ECI__c from Account limit 1];
    ServiceTerritory st = [Select Id,DndNumber__c from ServiceTerritory limit 1];
    st.DndNumber__c = 'P1234';
    update st;
    WorkType wr = [Select Id from WorkType limit 1];
    ServiceResource  sr = [Select Id from ServiceResource limit 1];
    Opportunity opp = [Select Id from Opportunity limit 1];
    Test.startTest();
    ServiceAppointment sa = CastTestHelper.mockServiceAppointment(opp, st, wr, sr, DateTime.now().addHours(5)); 
    CastTestHelper.mockServiceAppointmentResource(sa, sr);

    CastXlobDisposition.syncMeetingOutcome(sa.Id, 'Meeting Held');
 
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertEquals(sa.Outcome_of_Meeting__c,  'Meeting outcome should be updated to "Meeting Held"');
}


Don't System.assertEquals need expected value, actual value, message? It looks you have one value and a message.

The main issue
You're using the wrong version of the System.assertEquals() method.
There are 2 versions. One takes 2 arguments, the other takes 3.
System.assertEquals(<expected value>, <actual value>);
System.assertEquals(<expected value>, <actual value>, <custom message>);
The 2 argument version compares the two arguments to one another, and throws an exception if they aren't the same. Meeting Held is not the same as Meeting outcome should be updated to "Meeting Held".
The Meeting outcome should be updated to "Meeting Held" bit is almost certainly a custom message that you want to tack onto the exception. To specify that, you'd want the 3 argument version, e.g.
System.assertEquals('Meeting Held', sa.Outcome_of_Meeting__c, 'Meeting outcome should be updated to "Meeting Held"');
Also worth noting, Salesforce has (for a couple of releases now) an Assert class that has a few nicer things. The equivalent here would be Assert.areEqual('Meeting Held', sa.Outcome_of_Meeting__c, 'Meeting outcome should be updated to "Meeting Held"');
Also
remember that you need to do 2 things:

create/use an HttpCalloutMock to mock the callout (tests can't make actual callouts)
re-query your test record after Test.stopTest() but before your assertion(s) to get updated data.

The method you're testing is only passed an Id, and not the record instance itself. So the sa instance from the test itself will not be updated simply by running syncMeetingOutcome(). Even if you were using another async interface like Queueable that allows you to pass in SObject records as a whole, I'm unsure if the mechanism Salesforce uses to gather & run async code would preserve the reference.
+edit: A quick test reveals that changes made to an object instance in a Queueable are not reflected on the instance of that object created in the test. The reference is broken (and this makes sense in my mind).
tl;dr: Just query the record again to get updated data
